# Resolve users group membership in AssignedTo on work-item-queries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I assign work-items to user-groups in TFS. Lets say, I have a task assigned to the group [Devlopers]. Now I want to setup the Team Query "My Tasks" so that every member of [Developers] will see the task.

I tried the following operator/value-combinations in the query-editor (the square-brackets are added for visual reasons):

- [Assigned To] [In Group] [@Me]
- [Assigned To] [Contains] [@Me]
- [Assigned To] [=] [@Me]
- [Assigned To] [In] [@Me]

What I really need is something like @MyGroups instead of @Me. How can one achieve this?

If it isn't possible to this, what is the sence of Assign-To-Group in TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been wanting to do exactly the same thing, and found the following "work-around" which enables some of the functionality as you want.

For this to work you'll have to either:

1. create multiple dashboards
2. create multiple lists, and only show the correct one for the respective group the person is in

[image: multiple dashboards - one per team]

[image: Filter Options]

bare in mind this is after you have altered the work items to enable assigning to groups.
You'll then create a query for each of those groups as you need to specify the group name.

What I did was create a dashboard for each team, and on the dashboard had any "todo" items / change requests / tasks / bugs / etc.

It isn't possible to have a "is in my group" filter, unfortunately.

Comment: That should do the job for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the field "Assigned To" to a group, TFS only support setting a valid user.

You can change the Work Item Type definition to remove the constraint "validuser" and save any kind of text inside the field but don't expect to get groups that way.

This is a "complaint" many made to Microsoft for years but it stays as it always have been: no group.

You have to change the WIQ (Work Item Query) to use other fields to get the result you want. Looking at the example you gave I strongly encourage you to scope this query with the state, the area and iteration.

Comment: But I'm assigning groups to workitems already! You can achieve this by changing the WIT with TFS Power Commands as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422653/managing-users-in-the-tfs-work-items-assigned-to-field.

Comment: I work as a ALM Consultant with TFS for now almost 8 years, I customized tons of Process Template, trust me, you can't do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thats ok, I believe you. But explain the following to me: Fact 1) I'm able to setup Assign To so that it takes groups. Fact 2) I'm not able to use this in queries so that group members will receive work items. Question: WTH is Fact 1 useful for?

Comment: Fact 1 is only possible because you removed the constraint! And this constraint was what made the particularities of the Assigned To field compared to just a common field. It would have been wise from Microsoft to "lock" this constraint in the process template to prevent guys like you to remove it, but there's no such feature, you can do whatever you want in the Process Template editor, which is pretty risky.

Comment: OK but I did it not only because I was able to but also because this was a recommendation from Microsoft-people. But anyway, I got your point and your probably right, so I rate your answer up now. Thanks a lot.