# I assigned a TFS work item to an Active Directory group. It won't appear in work item queries for users in that group. How can I make it appear?

Tags: tfs, active-directory

We have some groups in Active Directory which are appearing in the TFS "assigned to" field's dropdown. I belong to the Contractors group. However, if I assign a work item to that group, I don't see it under a query for work items assigned to me. How can I include work items assigned to the groups I belong to into a query for my own work items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's  impossible to have a "in my group" filter for now. You could try the workaround  mentioned by *Neville* in this quetion [Resolve users group membership in AssignedTo on work-item-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174068/resolve-users-group-membership-in-assignedto-on-work-item-queries)

Note for this to work you'll have to either:

1. create multiple dashboards
2. create multiple lists, and only show the correct one for the
   respective group the person is in

---

Update

Add a small sample for your reference:
[image]

Comment: So what you're saying is I need to create multiple queries, one for my own user account, and one for each group I'm in? There's no way to even create a query with an "or" condition?

Comment: No, you don't have to create multiple querires , you can use "or " . And you need to group the clauses. I have create a sample above for your reference.